# Seleção de Objetos Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Bom, vou direto ao ponto, poderiam me da uma força nesse script que tou fazendo, ele seleciona usando botoes -1 e 1, até que funciona mais o anterior fica bugado

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ObjectSelection : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] ObjetosSelecionado;


    private int Selecao;


    public void ProximaSelecao(){

        ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (false);

        if (Selecao >= ObjetosSelecionado.Length - 1) {

            Selecao = 0;
            ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (true);

        } else {

            Selecao++;
            ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (true);


        }
    }
  public void AnteriorSelecao(){
        ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (true);

        if (Selecao >= ObjetosSelecionado.Length -1) {

            Selecao = 0;
            ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (false);

        } else {

            Selecao++;
            ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (false);

        }
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        for (int i = 0; i < ObjetosSelecionado.Length; i++) {

            ObjetosSelecionado [i].SetActive (false);

            Selecao = 0;
            ObjetosSelecionado [0].SetActive (true);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito você quer fazer ele ir selecionando um por um como uma fila, da uma estudada no código que é bem simples entender.

```
public void ProximaSelecao()
{
    ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (false);
    Selecao++;
    if (Selecao > ObjetosSelecionado.Length - 1) 
    {
        Selecao = 0;
    }
    ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (true);
}

public void AnteriorSelecao()
{
    ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (false);
    Selecao--;
    if (Selecao < 0) 
    {
        Selecao = ObjetosSelecionado.Length -1;
    }
    ObjetosSelecionado [Selecao].SetActive (true);
}
```

Comment: se é fácil pra ti, então vc pode me da uma força, na primeira seleção próximo eu consigo mais o anterior é que me parou

Comment: O código que eu coloquei não funciona? @Nitecki

Comment: agora foi o inverso, o anterior funciona mais o proximo n

Comment: Acho que agora vai, tinha um igual sobrando que não deixava selecionar a ultima posição

Comment: e eu achando que era necessário um for, muito obg pela ajuda funcionou